# How to write a comparator function in python to sort dates

Tags: python

I would like to write a comparator function to sort the following list of dates

```
timestamps = ['2011-06-2', '2011-08-05', '2011-02-04', '2010-1-14', '2010-12-13', '2010-1-12', '2010-2-11', '2010-2-07', '2010-12-02', '2011-11-30', '2010-11-26', '2010-11-23', '2010-11-22', '2010-11-16']
```

How to do that?

UPDATE:

I have this: `timestamps.sort(key=lambda x: time.mktime(time.strptime(x,"%Y-%m-%d")))`

But i want to write a comparator function.

Comment: Those are strings, not dates. Convert them to dates first, then sort in the regular manner.

Comment: Have you made *any* effort at all to do this yourself?  If so, if you share it, someone might be able to help.

Comment: Python has deprecated the `cmp` argument to `sort` in favor of `key`.  Why do you want to write a comparator function?

Comment: @dan04 Because I don't want to use any built in modules.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not the way to do it, even if it produces the correct result..

```
timestamps.sort(key=lambda d:"%d%02d%02d"%tuple(map(int,d.split('-'))))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one of the ways to do it:

```
from datetime import datetime

timestamps = ['2011-06-2', '2011-08-05', '2011-02-04', '2010-1-14', '2010-12-13', '2010-1-12', '2010-2-11', '2010-2-07', '2010-12-02', '2011-11-30', '2010-11-26', '2010-11-23', '2010-11-22', '2010-11-16']

converted_timestamps = [datetime.strptime(x, '%Y-%m-%d') for x in timestamps] 
sorted_timestamps = sorted(converted_timestamps)
sorted_timestamps_as_string = [datetime.strftime(date, "%Y-%m-%d") for date in sorted_timestamps]
print(sorted_timestamps_as_string)
```

Output:

> $ python tes.py
>
> ['2010-01-12', '2010-01-14', '2010-02-07',
> '2010-02-11', '2010-11-16', '2010-11-22', '2010-11-23', '2010-11-26',
> '2010-12-02', '2010-12-13', '2011-02-04', '2011-06-02', '2011-08-05',
> '2011-11-30']

I find it more readable.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to do approach it. Convert to a `datetime` object, sort, then convert back to strings.

```
from datetime import datetime
def sort_dates(string_dates):
    dates = [datetime.strptime(string_date, "%Y-%m-%d") for string_date in string_dates]
    dates.sort()
    return [datetime.strftime(date, "%Y-%m-%d") for date in dates]
```

**Sample Output:**

```
>>> print sort_dates(['2011-06-2', '2011-08-05', '2011-02-04', '2010-1-14', '2010-12-13', '2010-1-12', '2010-2-11', '2010-2-07', '2010-12-02', '2011-11-30', '2010-11-26', '2010-11-23', '2010-11-22', '2010-11-16'])
['2010-01-12', '2010-01-14', '2010-02-07', '2010-02-11', '2010-11-16', '2010-11-22', '2010-11-23', '2010-11-26', '2010-12-02', '2010-12-13', '2011-02-04', '2011-06-02', '2011-08-05', '2011-11-30']
```